# Why my responsive chart option settings doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to make my charts responsive, using echarts.js. I found [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Responsive%20Mobile-End) that I can use the property media and query.

The problem is that I do not see any change when I change the width.

```
let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('barchart'));
 
        let option = {
            baseOption: { // baseOption
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: 'Hashtag {b} <br /> Tweets: {c}'
                },
                toolbox: {
                    feature: {
                        dataView: {},
                        restore: {},
                        saveAsImage: {},                           
                    },
                    left: '1%',
                    top:'top',
                    right:'auto',
                    bottom:'auto'
                },
                grid: {
                    left: '2%',
                    top: '17%',
                    right: 'auto',
                    bottom: '10%',
                    containLabel: true
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    axisTick: {
                        alignWithLabel: true,
                        interval: 0
                      },
                      axisLabel: {
                        interval: 0,
                        rotate: 45,
                        width: 78,
                        overflow: 'truncate'
                      },
                      axisPointer: {
                        show: true,
                        type: 'shadow'
                      },
                    data: hashtags
                
                    
                },
                yAxis: { 
                    type: 'value'
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Tweet count',
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: countOfEachHashTag,
                        showBackground: true,
                        backgroundStyle: {
                            color: 'rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2)'
                        },
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'top'
                        },
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: 'rgb(8,72,103)'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            media: [
                {
                    query: {
                        maxWidth: 576
                    },
                    option: {
                        grid: {
                            left: 'auto',
                            top: 'auto',
                            right: 'auto',
                            bottom: 'auto',
                            width: '406',
                            height: '600',
                            containLabel: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
    myChart.setOption(option);
```

My code seems correct, as per the example, but I do not see any change in the container's width and height when I resize my window and the container size descreases too.

My html code for this chart is this:

```
<div id="barChartCollapse" class="collapse show">
     <div id="barchart" style="width: auto;height:600px;">

     </div>
</div>
```

Is something missing?

minWidth, as per the example, works, but maxWidth doesn't. The example link that I provided specifically points that `width, height, aspectRatio (height / width), each of which can add min or max as prefix`. That's very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a responsive chart :

- Set the chart's container size. In Echarts, the size of the container has to be set before the chart is initialized. (You already have that)

```js
<div id="barChartCollapse" class="collapse show">
   <div id="barchart" style="width:auto; height:600px;"> //or width: 100%;

   </div>
</div>
```

- Add an event listener on the window 'resize' event and resize your chart here. Check [Echarts `resize()` documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.resize).

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('barchart'));
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  myChart.resize();
});
```

This way, your chart will always fit your window's width as you resize it.

Also check this complete [documentation on the subject](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/chart-size/).

Comment: As @Deunz pointed out, you could also use a completely custom size management (I also did that in a project) but that's more difficult to set up.

Comment: I am stupid, hahaha. Yeah, the resize method was necessary. Check my comment above. When I add the resize method, my query works and it does what I want. So silly of me. Thank you. It seems it is working.

Comment: Mark answer as proper response => this gives points to author aswell to indicate other people with same problem ;)

Comment: I just did! :) Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think the heigh of you div is fixed by the `height:600px`, so chart cannot adapt

```
 <div id="barchart" style="width: auto;height:600px;">

 </div>
```

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, should it? I am descreasing width the check the change in the responsiveness. Nevertheless, I changed my html code to this:

`<div id="barChartCollapse" class="collapse show" style="width: auto;height:600px;">
                    <div id="barchart" style="width: auto;height:100%;">
                    </div>
</div>`

And yet the maxWidth does not work. The div with the id `barchart` should have dimensions, because otherwise the chart won't be rendered and appear.

Comment: I think I had same kind of problems with ngx-charts, I ended up with a custom Height management

Comment: I made my parent div to `height: 100%` and the container div to `height: auto`. But still it does not work. 

How can I make a custom height management, if this is indeed the problem?

Comment: Really complex custom method to calculate height based on the vh css unit : try `height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as intended. Here is a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6cjnxFUpMpRqyAbowA2SrT2jrB4VEZUhLCi_MQe6BTUdP4Q0MqhHkJgIjEAjACsAAw8sABMAMwl5WUALKVleQAcpXkVBa21AOwNAGxF1pmwdiSDJAC2GhC5sR7uCQCOSlxucR7jjBiqEAJg2kS9xWvDQ-igkDCrCaSsRgJX16TaVBCs2mB0xQCkvMceAO47PafIo_U4JIxvD6wEp_UgAI2AYDAwHGRFhj1I9BgOTSABlGPCqP4iGAOEo4SNrlTSDTbHYANxAA):

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
    }
  ],
  media: [
    {
      query: {
        maxWidth: 650
      },
      option: {
        grid: {
          height: '50%',
          width: '50%',
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          containLabel: true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

If you now change the window size to smaller than 650 pixel, the chart will shrink to 50% size and jump to the lower right corner.

What exactly do you want to achieve?

---

On a side note, I dont think that `left: 'auto'` works as its not documented for [grid](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.left).

Comment: I am trying to make my charts responsive, mobile-first. So, I thought I will add a maxWidth of a standard breakpoint for mobiles (e.g 576px) to decrease the grid's width and height. Up until breakpoint of 576 px, I wanted to have my grid's width and height to 406x600.

The container of my chart is the div with the `id=barchart`. And that container exists inside another div.

Cannot figure out, though, why my maxWidth doesn't work as intended, like yours.

Thank you for the correction. Indeed, `left: auto` does not exist.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the framework you are using. I would try to build a minimal example (similar to mine) to check for that.

Comment: When I tried the solution from @A mere dev, adding the resize() method, the maxWidth worked for some reason. I noticed in the developer tools that the width of my container didn't reduce when I resize my window. I think that because the width didn't change, the maxWidth query couldn't see any width changes, and that's why I couldn't see anything. When I add the resize method properly, as A mere dev suggests, width is now decreasing, and the maxWidth query pops and does what I want.